# Mostrar/Esconder Informação ao clicar

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho Valores na minha aplicação que precisão de uma certa privacidade, o código funciona bem, só gostaria de saber como ocultar os "***" quando mostrar os valores.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none">
  <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
    Valor
  </h6>
</div>

<p class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">***</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mas se vc ocultar o `***` onde vc vai clicar para fechar ocultar novamente?

Comment: a ideia é clicar no 'valor' e voltar a ser '***'

Comment: O `e.preventDefault();` é desnecessário porque não tem função nenhuma nesse contexto. O clique no parágrafo não causa nenhuma ação. Vc usaria se em vez do parágrafro fosse um `<a>`.

Comment: usar o valor em um input type text estilizado e com um evento de clique para mudar para password e depois para text seria ridículo?

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz uma alteração no seu código que irá ocultar o `***` e voltar para ele ao clicar no valor.
A alteração foi adicionar a classe `btn-toggle` também na `div` do valor e adicionar o `data-element` referenciando a `div` dos `***`.
Na função adicionei o `$(this).toggle();` para realizar o toggle também no elemento clicado.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(this).toggle(); // vai fazer o toggle no elemento clicado
    $(el).toggle(); // vai fazer o toggle no elemento que é data do elemento clicado
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none" data-element="#divSecreta" class="btn-toggle">
  <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
    Valor
  </h6>
</div>

<div class="btn-toggle" id="divSecreta" data-element="#minhaDiv">***</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pegando como base a resposta do @Lucas Ayrosa, refatorei e simplifiquei o código.

Você pode usar o atributo `data-element` e realizar `toggle` nos dois elementos.

```js
$("[data-element]").click(function(e) {
    $('[data-element]').toggle(); // vai fazer o toggle nos elementos
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none" data-element="#divSecreta">
    <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
        Valor
    </h6>
</div>

<div class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">***</div>
```

---

Referência: [Toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

Se você só quer alternar o texto e os asteriscos, não tem porque tem um `div` separada, ou qualquer estrutura muito complexa...

Você poderia simplesmente guardar o texto original em um atributo e alternar o HTML do elemento.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$('.hidden-text')
    // Começa os textos com ****
    .html(function(i, old_text) {
      return "*".repeat(this.dataset.text.length);
    })
    // Alerna os texto
    .on('click', function() {
        let text = this.dataset.text;
        
        if (this.is_visible) {
            this.innerHTML = "*".repeat(text.length);
        } else {
            this.innerHTML = text;
        }
        
        this.is_visible = !this.is_visible;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="hidden-text" data-text="Meu texto escondido"></p>
<p class="hidden-text" data-text="outro texto escondido"></p>
```

---

O funcionamento é simples:

1. Uso o método [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) para "inicializar" todos os elementos com asteriscos;
2. Ao clicar no elemento verifico se a propriedade `is_visible` é verdadeira

   - Se sim, escondo o texto substituindo seu conteúdo por asteriscos (estou utilizando o método [`String.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) para repetir o asterísco N vezes);
   - Se não, mostro o texto substituindo seu conteúdo pelo texto contido em `data-text` (veja mais sobre `data-*` na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*));

Note que a propriedade `is_visible` não existe, eu que a "inventei" para guardar o estado daquele objeto em memória sem precisar acessar o DOM.

Comment: A boa alma gostaria de explicar o downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer desta forma usando o `.one()` que dispara o evento de clique apenas 1 vez. Inclusive funciona para vários elementos:

```js
$(function() {
   $(".btn-toggle").click(function(){
      var data = $(this).data('element'); // pega o data-element
      var div = $(data); // pega a div com id igual ao data-element
      $(this).hide(); // esconde o ***
      div
      .show() // mostra a div do valor
      .one("click", function(){
         $(this).hide(); // esconde a div do valor
         $("[data-element='"+data+"']").show(); // mostra o ***
      });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none">
  <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
    Valor
  </h6>
</div>

<p class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">***</p>

<div id="minhaDiv2" style="display:none">
  <h6 class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
    Valor2
  </h6>
</div>

<p class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv2">***</p>
```